# Obtain SQL insert statements from Database Initializer seed method

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, seeding

I have read this [blog](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/): which explains the difference between Database Initializer seeds and Migration seed methods.

I am working on a project, that uses code-first Entity Framework, with migrations enabled. A Database Initializer seed is present and it will execute on my local database, when the database is created.

But in the production environment, I do not have the rights to add databases myself. I need to run update-database -script from package manager console on an empty newly created database and then execute the migrations manually.

As I do not have direct access from my development environment to the production database server, I am thinking out loud: there is no gain in rewriting the Database Initializer to a Migrations Seed.

**How can I obtain the script (SQL), that is the insert statements, defined in the Database Initializer seed method?**

Of course I can :

1. run update-database on an empty existing database. (no seed method is executed)
2. run update-database on a non-existing database. (seed method is executed)

Do a SQL compare between the 2 databases and get the INSERT queries that way.

But there should be an easier way right?

Why does the `update-database -script` not show the INSERT statements from the database initializer seed method in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the logging described in [Entity Framework Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) will catch the SQL from the DatabaseInitializer. If not you can try to find a 3rd party profiler to catch your SQL. Personally, I use [ORM Profiler](http://ormprofiler.com/) and it catches everything, however it is not free.

And yes, there should be an easier way.

Comment: It might not be what I was looking for in this specific case, but I bookmarked the information. I did not know this functionality existed. I will probably make use of it in the near future for logging purposes.